# Is a lambda in a default template parameter considered part of the immediate context?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

Is the following code well-formed C++17?

```
template <typename T, int = [](auto t) { decltype(t)::invalid; return 0; }(T{})>
constexpr int f(T) { return 0; }
constexpr int f(...) { return 1; }

static_assert(f(0) == 1);
```

clang and edg accept it, while msvc and gcc<sup>1</sup> reject it. I can't find anything that would say that this is a hard error, but I also can't find anything that would say that this is a deduction failure.

In C++20, there is this paragraph ([[temp.deduct]p9](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#9)):

> A *lambda-expression* appearing in a function type or a template parameter is not considered part of the immediate context for the purposes of template argument deduction.

which makes it clear that the lambda is not part of the immediate context. But what about C++17?

---

<sup>1</sup>: gcc has a bug with `auto` in this context, but rewriting it using explicit template parameters for the lambda gets you the same error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's plain ill-formed in C++17, if I gather correctly.

> **[expr.prim.lambda]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda#2) A lambda-expression shall not appear in an unevaluated operand,
>   in **a template-argument**, [...]
>
> **[temp.param]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#9) A default template-argument **is a template-argument**
>   ([temp.arg]) specified after = in a template-parameter.

In both cases "template-argument" is the same normative term. So I think Clang and edg err by accepting the code in the OP as valid C++17.

Comment: @StoryTeller: unfortunately, gcc, with little tweaks, accepts this code as well: https://godbolt.org/z/87cf3M

Comment: Aaaand, clang is failing terribly ; ). So, this is both compilers bug.

Comment: Do note that this has been made well-formed for C++20: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0315r4.pdf. One could argue that it's just a matter of time travel as a compiler implementation strategy ;)

Comment: @Griwes - They kept telling us UB can result in time travel. I never believed it until now.