# Deduce type of lambda decayed to function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

So I've made this template to define functors inline:

```
template <typename F, F* f>
struct AsFunctor
{
    template <typename... Args>
    std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...> operator()(Args&&... args) { return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
};
```

which can be used like so:

```
std::unique_ptr<char, AsFunctor<void(char*), +[](char* c) {/*STUFF*/}>> p;
```

Works great except that I have to needlessly declare the type of my function twice. Is there any way I can make the compiler deduce it? I've tried decltype in various ways such as

```
#define AS_FUNCTOR(lambda) AsFunctor<decltype(+lambda), +lambda>
```

but they're all compile errors as lambdas can't appear in an unevaluated context.

Comment: They can't appear as template arguments either if memory serves. I have no idea how your original works.

Comment: I did remember correctly. GCC rejects this as c++17 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1ac1398a09c3b35

Comment: Whoops, I forgot a closing angle bracket. Try again.

Comment: Still the same error... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81a388a028ee537a

Comment: Odd, MSVC accepts it: https://godbolt.org/z/S1F_5u though it seems this feature was technically pushed back to c++2x.

Comment: MSVC is being non-compliant. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595159) why it's not valid C++17. It could be valid C++20... I think. I'm trying to figure out an alternative for you at the moment.

Comment: But anyway, you won't need this at all in C++20. You could just write `std::unique_ptr<char, [](char* c) {/*STUFF*/}>> p;` - no helper needed.

Comment: c++17 allows `template <auto f>`, so with lambda in template from C++2a, you would be fine.

Comment: As an aside, why define your own `AsFunctor` instead of using [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `auto` for the functor and then use `decltype` to deduce the type.

```
template <auto F>
struct AsFunctor {
  template <typename... Args>
  std::invoke_result_t<decltype(F), Args...> operator()(Args&&... args) {
    return F(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};

int main() {
  int i;
  std::unique_ptr<char, AsFunctor<+[](char* c) { /*STUFF*/ }>> p;
}
```

I don't know the context, but generally you don't need any custom functor types (it's better to use templates right away, look at any example from the STL) or `std::function`.

Comment: See the comments on the question. Especially those older than your answer.